# Recording Robo-Script From Android Studio Failed

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-test-lab

I am trying to generate a simple robo script for my app in order to run it on Firebase׳s Tast-Lab.
While following the instructions: In Android Studio click -> Tools -> Firebase -> Test Lab -> Record Robo script. The app is being built, but the UI of the test lab never showed up.

Here is an example i saw on some guide:
[image]

But there is no option to finalize the recording process, and I don't even see the generated script.

Using Android Studio version: **Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1**
On macOS 13.2

Any idea what am I missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is probably some issue preventing building and/or launching your app in debug mode. If there is an exception/error thrown, it would show up as a flickering icon in the bottom right of Android Studio window.

You could also double check if you get the same problem with launching Espresso Test Recorder (Run -> Record Espresso Test).

Comment: Thanks!
I will try to look for it